# Blur on MKMapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, blur

I know this question has been asked before, but I am trying to put a blur on a map view in my app. Everything I've tried just tints the map including code like this:

```
var darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
blurView.frame = mapView.bounds
mapView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Is there a way to actually blur the map?

Comment: Do you need dynamic blur or static blur? If static - I can suggest a workaround - to create map snapshot as UIImage and blur it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `blurView` to `mapView`'s superview?

Works fine for me in Playground:

[image: Blurred map view in Playground]

Comment: I have. It blurs other objects on the screen like buttons but not the mapview

Comment: @CalebRudnicki  See my updated answer... seems to work fine for me in a Playground. Are you using `mapView.bounds` before it is set?